# Best way to have a left and right aligned View in the same parent?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Here's my code.  I have tried this in a TableLayout as well.  Everything lines to the left, regardless of what I do.  Wish this (what seems to be a normal use-case) was detailed better.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/actionbar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@layout/lightblue_gradient"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dip"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_search" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/actionbar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@layout/lightblue_gradient"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_search" />
</RelativeLayout>
```